# how to create manifest script

Tags: awk

I am having list of file in a directory like

```
sales_01
product_01
```

and I m encrypting those files in the same directory. Now I am having list of files such as

```
sales_01
product_01
sales_01.gpg
product_01.gpg
```

Now my question is I have to create the manifest file which are having the column. double quotes should present

```
"original_filename" "original_filesize" "encrypted_filesize" "md5sum(value of encrypted file)"
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume your filenames don't have embedded newlines.

On Linux:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
find /some/dir -type f -maxdepth 1 \! -name '*.gpg' | \
while read -r f; do
    esc=${f##*/}
    esc=${esc//\\/\\\\}
    esc=${esc//\"/\\\"}
    md5=$(md5sum "$f".gpg | awk '{print $1}')
    printf '"%s" "%d" "%d" "%s"\n' "$esc" $(stat -c %s "$f") $(stat -c %s "$f".gpg) "$md5"
done
```

On *BSD:

```
#! /bin/sh
find /some/dir -type f -maxdepth 1 \! -name '*.gpg' | \
while read -r f; do
    esc=$(printf '%s\n' "$f" | sed 's#.*/##; s/\([\\"]\)/\\\1/g')
    md5=$(md5 -q "$f".gpg)
    printf '"%s" "%d" "%d" "%s"\n' "$esc" $(stat -f %z "$f") $(stat -f %z "$f".gpg) "$md5"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Well it isn't very pretty, but this should work.

```
for i in $(ls | cut -d. -f1 | uniq); do if [ -f $i.gpg ]; then base_size=$(ls  -al $i| cut -d" " -f5); gpg_size=$(  ls  -al $i.gpg| cut -d" " -f5); md5_sum=$(md5sum $i.gpg | awk '{ print $1 }') ; echo  $i $base_size $gpg_size $md5; fi; done
```

Comment: Now assume one of the files is named `Mr.Proper 01`. :)